# How does the Linux desktop perform system actions?

Tags: sudo, desktop

The Linux desktop can perform several actions which is otherwise not available to the user when logged in from a terminal. Actions such as system shutdown, and changing system time are accessible only to a sudo user after entering the password.
How does this work. Is there a root daemon running which takes command from the login user. Please guide me to the right answer.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the Linux desktop". What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 13.10 Unity (ubuntu-desktop) . I presumed the idea is same across distros, hence asked here instead of askubuntu.

Comment: It's not a matter of distro, it's a matter of which desktop environment you use - KDE might not do it the same way as Gnome does, nor as Unity does. (They might all use the same technique though.)

Comment: Probably the answers/comments on "*how things work under the hood* (a.k.a. GUI)" here -> http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101074/how-does-mounting-on-the-gui-work-under-the-hood, explained on the example of `mount`(ing) might help a bit in understanding. I, personally, chew heavily on them at the moment

Comment: @Mat AFAIK they've all standardized on D-Bus now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently on Ubuntu, the actual shutdown is performed by `console-kit-daemon`, the [ConsoleKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ConsoleKit/) daemon, which runs with root privileges. The ConsoleKit daemon receives the shutdown request from the desktop panel application via [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/). The policy that allows unprivileged processes to speak to privileged processes is handled by [polkit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/) (formerly PolicyKit). You can emulate the ConsoleKit invocation via `dbus-send` if you wish. In particular, to tell ConsoleKit to perform a shutdown you can do:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" \
/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

On Ubuntu, ConsoleKit replaced the [Hardware Abstraction Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_%28software%29) (HAL), a subsystem  aimed to allow desktop applications to discover and use the hardware of the host system through a portable and abstract API, regardless of the type of the underlying hardware. HAL is today deprecated in most Linux distributions. The equivalent `dbus-send` invocation using HAL is:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal \ 
/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer/org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown
```

Currently, ConsoleKit is not actively maintained. The focus of the [freedesktop.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org) project has shifted towards the built-in seat/user/session management of the [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) init system called [systemd-logind](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html). How this will affect distributions who adopted their own init systems, like [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) in Ubuntu, remains to be seen.